# How can I design the left border for the below component?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, css-selectors

I need to design a component, which looks like below : [image]

How can I design the left border ? Should it be done via some svg icon or it could be done by border-radius and css pseudo classes (before, after)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use `box-shadow`. Set a border-radius to the element itself and then add a non-transparent `box-shadow` without blur-radius and offset it with a negative horizontal position:

```css
span {
  font-size: 2em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: -5px 0 0 0 rgb(0, 0, 255);
}
```

```html
<span>Some Text</span>
```